# How can I improve compile times when I have a large HashMap literal?

Tags: rust

I have a very large HashMap of physical measurements (300k+ entries of 3-element tuples), which I'd like to keep as a HashMap (I could move it out to a SQLite DB and query it, but I'd rather not, for performance reasons). Including it as a literal makes compile times…long.
Is there a better approach? Could I serialise it to disk in a binary format, and load it as a HashMap when the binary executes / the library is loaded? Developing and testing using a subset works fine, but I need the full data for production…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you're hardcoding a hash map? That seems to be a Perfect Hashing problem, see the https://github.com/sfackler/rust-phf crate.

As for the compile times, offload the hash table into a separate crate and Cargo will only recompile this crate when the hash table data changes.

Comment: https://github.com/BurntSushi/fst is also a way to produce perfect hashing, albeit likely with differ trade offs and definitely with different requirements/limitations and probably not as convenient as rust-phf.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 Oh, right, I still haven't got to read http://blog.burntsushi.net/transducers/, thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: This turned out to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @urschrei I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

If you're fine with developing and testing with a smaller set of data, then you can use conditional compilation. Here is a simple example:

```
#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
const VALUE: u32 = 0;

#[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]
const VALUE: u32 = 1;

fn main() {
    println!("value: {}", VALUE);
}
```

If you compile this without optimizations ("debug" mode), then `debug_assertions` will be true, and `VALUE` will be equal to 0, but if you compile it with optimizations ("release" mode), then `debug_assertions` will be false, and `VALUE` will be equal to 1.

This maps very nicely to Cargo's debug and release modes (`cargo build` and `cargo build --release`), so this way you can make your map smaller for debug build and make it full size for release build.

Naturally, serializing your data and loading it back is also possible. You can use lots of libraries for automatic serialization, for example, [bincode](https://github.com/TyOverby/bincode) or [rustc_serialize::json](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc-serialize/rustc_serialize/json/index.html) or [serde_json](https://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde_json/serde_json/index.html). If you want to know how exactly those libraries should be used, then you should ask another question, if their docs for some reason aren't clear enough.